# how can i find a model from contigency table?

Tags: r

I have a 3  ways contigency table, say A, B, C, all binary data (1 or 0), and several different numbers in the table; like this:

```
                                  A
                            1           0
                            D           D
                          1   0       1   0

           1    C    1   21   15     11    30
     B               0   15   11      5    8
           0    C    1    5   42     3     14
                     0    4    3      2    15
```

D is success or failure.

I want to use r to find the model of the success, say prob(D=1) = a + bx1 + cx2 + dx3
which x1, x2, x3 are A, B, C variables.

So what can I do?

I tried model = glm(D~A+B+C, binomial)

but is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert your contingency table
(I assume it really is what you have) 
into a data.frame.

```
# Sample data
n <- 200
d <- data.frame(
  A = sample(0:1, n, replace=TRUE),
  B = sample(0:1, n, replace=TRUE),
  C = sample(0:1, n, replace=TRUE),
  D = sample(0:1, n, replace=TRUE)
)
d <- table(d)

# Put the data in a data.frame
library(reshape)
d <- melt(d)

# Compute the regression
glm(D ~ A+B+C, data=d, family=binomial(), weights=value)
```